# C++ - Merge Sort - Can't Identify What's Wrong

Tags: c++, mergesort

So, I've been trying to create a merge sort algorithm, but for some reasons the outcome isn't correct. I've tried printing the high, low and middle values, and also the array values at every change, and I noticed that the number of some values weren't even correct. So for example, if I typed in a 3, the final result would include multiple 3s. But what really confuses me is that this doesn't happen when I input 4 values or less, I've only noticed it in five or higher input values. I don't know if it's the computer or the compiler that's changing some of those values, or if it's my code that is the problem.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int num;
int * array = new int [num];
int * sub = new int [num];

void sort (int low, int mid, int high) {
    std::cout << "Low, mid, high: " << low << ", " << mid << ", " << high << ".\n";

    int a,b,c,d;
    a = low;
    b = low;
    c = mid;

    while ((a < mid) && (c < high)) {
        if (array[a] < array[c]) {
            sub[b] = array[a];
            a++;
        } else {
            sub[b] = array[c];
            c++;
        }
        b++;
    }
    while (a == mid && c < high) {
        sub[b] = array[c];
        c++;
        b++;
    }
    while (c == high && a < mid) {
        sub[b] = array[a];
        a++;
        b++;
    }
    for (d = low; d < high; d++) {
        array[d] = sub[d];
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            std::cout << array[i];
            if (i != num - 1) {
                std::cout << ", ";
            } else {
                std::cout << ".\n";
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Done!\n";
}
void split (int low, int high) {
    if (low < high - 1) {
        int mid = (low + high) / 2;
        split(low, mid);
        split(mid, high);
        sort(low, mid, high);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "This is a program that sorts integers.\n";
    std::cout << "How many numbers would you like to sort?\n";
    std::cin >> num;
    std::cout << "Please type in the numbers.\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        std::cin >> array[i];
    }
    split(0, num);
    std::cout << "Your sorted numbers are: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        std::cout << array[i];
        if (i != num - 1) {
            std::cout << ", ";
        } else {
            std::cout << ".\n";
        }
    }
    delete[] array;
    delete[] sub;

    return 0;
}
```

I also tried my code on my original compiler and an online shell, and it seemed that they produced two different results for the same test:

Original compiler:

```
This is a program that sorts integers.
How many numbers would you like to sort?
9
Please type in the numbers.
5
9
2
0
6
4
3
1
8
Low, mid, high: 0, 1, 2.
5, 9, 2, 0, 5, 9, 3, 1, 8.
5, 9, 2, 0, 5, 9, 3, 1, 8.
Done!
Low, mid, high: 2, 3, 4.
5, 9, 0, 0, 5, 9, 0, 2, 8.
5, 9, 0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 2, 8.
Done!
Low, mid, high: 0, 2, 4.
0, 9, 0, 2, 0, 2, 5, 9, 8.
0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 5, 9, 8.
0, 2, 5, 2, 0, 2, 5, 9, 8.
0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 2, 5, 9, 8.
Done!
Low, mid, high: 4, 5, 6.
0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 2, 5, 9, 0.
0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 2, 5, 9, 0.
Done!
Low, mid, high: 7, 8, 9.
0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 2, 5, 0, 0.
0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 2, 5, 0, 9.
Done!
Low, mid, high: 6, 7, 9.
0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 2, 0, 0, 9.
0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 2, 0, 5, 9.
0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 2, 0, 5, 9.
Done!
Low, mid, high: 4, 6, 9.
0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 2, 0, 5, 0.
0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0.
0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0.
0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0.
0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0.
Done!
Low, mid, high: 0, 4, 9.
0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.
0, 0, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.
0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0.
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0.
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 9.
Done!
Your sorted numbers are: 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 9.
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Online shell:

```
This is a program that sorts integers.
How many numbers would you like to sort?
9
Please type in the numbers.
5
9
2
0
6
4
3
1
8
Low, mid, high: 0, 1, 2.
5, 9, 2, 0, 6, 4, 3, 1, 5.
5, 9, 2, 0, 6, 4, 3, 1, 5.
Done!
Low, mid, high: 2, 3, 4.
5, 9, 0, 0, 6, 4, 3, 1, 5.
5, 9, 0, 2, 6, 4, 3, 1, 5.
Done!
Low, mid, high: 0, 2, 4.
0, 9, 0, 2, 6, 4, 3, 1, 0.
0, 2, 0, 2, 6, 4, 3, 1, 0.
0, 2, 5, 2, 6, 4, 3, 1, 0.
0, 2, 5, 9, 6, 4, 3, 1, 0.
Done!
Low, mid, high: 4, 5, 6.
0, 2, 5, 9, 4, 4, 3, 1, 0.
0, 2, 5, 9, 4, 6, 3, 1, 0.
Done!
Low, mid, high: 7, 8, 9.
0, 2, 5, 9, 4, 6, 3, 0, 0.
0, 2, 5, 9, 4, 6, 3, 0, 1.
Done!
Low, mid, high: 6, 7, 9.
0, 2, 5, 9, 4, 6, 0, 0, 1.
0, 2, 5, 9, 4, 6, 0, 1, 1.
0, 2, 5, 9, 4, 6, 0, 1, 3.
Done!
Low, mid, high: 4, 6, 9.
0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 6, 0, 1, 3.
0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 1, 0, 1, 3.
0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 1, 3, 1, 3.
0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 1, 3, 4, 3.
0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 1, 3, 4, 6.
Done!
Low, mid, high: 0, 4, 9.
0, 2, 5, 9, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0.
0, 0, 5, 9, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0.
0, 0, 1, 9, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0.
0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 4, 0.
0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 0.
0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 0.
0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 4, 0.
0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5, 0.
0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5, 9.
Done!
Your sorted numbers are: 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5, 9.
```

As you can see, I used the exact same numbers and code but got two completely different results, so I don't know if my code is wrong or if it is something else. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: It would be great if you solve it by your self my friend,

Comment: `int num; int * array = new int [num]; int * sub = new int [num];`...I'm fairly sure that allocating two arrays of 0 element each isn't what you want to do.

Comment: @T.C.: Ok, but like I said, it works when you have 4 or less input variables. It wouldn't have worked if it used two arrays with 0 elements.

Comment: @ICanCYou It's undefined behavior, which includes "appearing to work".

Comment: @T.C.: Ah, Ok. I changed the code to prevent that, and it seems to work just fine now. Thank you.

Comment: Since you solved the problem, can you post an answer to your own question so that future visitors to the site can see what's wrong?

Comment: To misquote Shakespeare: "The fault, dear @ICanCYou, lies not in our compilers, but in ourselves..."

Comment: Here at SO, please don't edit the question to say "solved". Instead, *accept* an answer with the solution by ticking the check mark next to the answer (can be your own answer, if no other answer has the right solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `num` was not defined when it was declared in the beginning of the code, since it was a global variable `num` was automatically assigned to `0`. Then `int * array = new int [num];` and `int * sub = new int [num];` were declared with `num` not yet defined by the user, creating two arrays with `0` elements. Trying to change these arrays caused undefined behavior, which included falsely making certain cases appear correct, and also in this case, using don't-care terms to change the list of numbers the user created.

In order to fix this problem, `int * array` and `int * sub` must only be defined after `num` is defined by the user. This also means that functions `split` and `sort` have to include the pointers to arrays as parameters.

Here's what the code should look like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

void sort (int *array, int *sub, int low, int mid, int high) {
int a = low;
int b = low;
int c = mid;

while ((a < mid) && (c < high)) {
    if (array[a] < array[c]) {
        sub[b] = array[a];
        a++;
    } else {
        sub[b] = array[c];
        c++;
    }
    b++;
}
while (a == mid && c < high) {
    sub[b] = array[c];
    c++;
    b++;
}
while (c == high && a < mid) {
    sub[b] = array[a];
    a++;
    b++;
}
for (int d = low; d < high; d++) {
    array[d] = sub[d];
}
}
void split (int *array, int *sub, int low, int high) {
if (low < high - 1) {
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    split(array, sub, low, mid);
    split(array, sub, mid, high);
    sort(array, sub, low, mid, high);
}
}

int main()
{
std::cout << "This is a program that sorts integers.\n";
std::cout << "How many numbers would you like to sort?\n";
int num;
std::cin >> num;
int * array = new int [num];
int * sub = new int [num];
std::cout << "Please type in the numbers.\n";
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    std::cin >> array[i];
}
split(array, sub, 0, num);
std::cout << "Your sorted numbers are: ";
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    std::cout << array[i];
    if (i != num - 1) {
        std::cout << ", ";
    } else {
        std::cout << ".\n";
    }
}
delete[] array;
delete[] sub;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a bottom up merge sort. Examples of both:

bottom up:

```
template <typename T>
T * BottomUpMergeSort(T a[], T b[], size_t n)
{
    for(size_t s = 1; s < n; s += 2)        // swap in place for 1st pass
        if(a[s] < a[s-1])
            std::swap(a[s], a[s-1]);
    for(size_t s = 2; s < n; s <<= 1){      // s = run size
        size_t ee = 0;                      // init end index
        while(ee < n){                      // merge pairs of runs
            size_t ll = ee;                 // ll = start of left  run
            size_t rr = ll+s;               // rr = start of right run
            if(rr >= n){                    // if only left run
                rr = n;
                BottomUpCopy(a, b, ll, rr); //   copy left run
                break;                      //   end of pass
            }
            ee = rr+s;                      // ee = end of right run
            if(ee > n)
                ee = n;
            BottomUpMerge(a, b, ll, rr, ee);
        }
        std::swap(a, b);                    // swap a and b
    }
    return a;                               // return sorted array
}

template <typename T>
void BottomUpCopy(T a[], T b[], size_t ll, size_t rr)
{
    while(ll < rr){                         // copy left run
        b[ll] = a[ll];
        ll++;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void BottomUpMerge(T a[], T b[], size_t ll, size_t rr, size_t ee)
{
    size_t o = ll;                          // b[]       index
    size_t l = ll;                          // a[] left  index
    size_t r = rr;                          // a[] right index

    while(1){                               // merge data
        if(a[l] <= a[r]){                   // if a[l] <= a[r]
            b[o++] = a[l++];                //   copy a[l]
            if(l < rr)                      //   if not end of left run
                continue;                   //     continue (back to while)
            while(r < ee){                  //   else copy rest of right run
                b[o++] = a[r++];
            }
            break;                          //     and return
        } else {                            // else a[l] > a[r]
            b[o++] = a[r++];                //   copy a[r]
            if(r < ee)                      //   if not end of right run
                continue;                   //     continue (back to while)
            while(l < rr){                  //   else copy rest of left run
                b[o++] = a[l++];
            }
            break;                          //     and return
        }
    }
}
```

top down, avoids copying of data after merge by alternating between two recursive functions:

```
template <typename T>
T * TopDownMergeSort(T a[], T b[], size_t n)
{
    TopDownMergeSortAtoA(a, b, 0, n);
    return a;
}

template <typename T>
void TopDownMergeSortAtoA(T a[], T b[], size_t ll, size_t ee)
{
    if (ee - ll > 1) {
        size_t rr = (ll + ee)>>1;           // midpoint, start of right half
        TopDownMergeSortAtoB(a, b, ll, rr);
        TopDownMergeSortAtoB(a, b, rr, ee);
        TopDownMerge(b, a, ll, rr, ee);     // merge b to a
    }
}

template <typename T>
void TopDownMergeSortAtoB(T a[], T b[], size_t ll, size_t ee)
{
    if (ee - ll > 1) {
        size_t rr = (ll + ee)>>1;           //midpoint, start of right half
        TopDownMergeSortAtoA(a, b, ll, rr);
        TopDownMergeSortAtoA(a, b, rr, ee);
        TopDownMerge(a, b, ll, rr, ee);     // merge a to b
    } else if ((ee - ll) == 1) {
        b[ll] = a[ll];
    }
}

template <typename T>
void TopDownMerge(T a[], T b[], size_t ll, size_t rr, size_t ee)
{
    size_t o = ll;                          // b[]       index
    size_t l = ll;                          // a[] left  index
    size_t r = rr;                          // a[] right index

    while(1){                               // merge data
        if(a[l] <= a[r]){                   // if a[l] <= a[r]
            b[o++] = a[l++];                //   copy a[l]
            if(l < rr)                      //   if not end of left run
                continue;                   //     continue (back to while)
            while(r < ee){                  //   else copy rest of right run
                b[o++] = a[r++];
            }
            break;                          //     and return
        } else {                            // else a[l] > a[r]
            b[o++] = a[r++];                //   copy a[r]
            if(r < ee)                      //   if not end of right run
                continue;                   //     continue (back to while)
            while(l < rr){                  //   else copy rest of left run
                b[o++] = a[l++];
            }
            break;                          //     and return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what I'm doing. I certainly know that I'm not doing a top-down merge sort.

Comment: The split function in the example code is the key part of a top down merge sort. It recursively splits arrays into halves, until the size is reduced to 1, and only then does it begin the actual merge process. A bottom up sort skips all that splitting logic and begins by treating an array of size n as n "runs" of size 1, merging pairs of runs to create runs of size 2, 4, ... until run size >= array size. Wiki examples: [top down](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation) and [bottom up](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation) .

Comment: The `split` function in the example code doesn't split until the sublist size is reduced to 1, it splits until the sublist size equals 2. Check the `if` statement in `split`: `if (low < high - 1)`. This means that the `sort` function is only activated if low is less than high by at least 2. That also means that the minimum difference between low and mid is 1, so `sort` is comparing two different values. So after the groups of 2 are sorted, then 2 groups are merged into 1, etc., until the whole array is sorted.

Comment: Assume split is called with a sublist size of 2, low = 0, high = 2. It then calculates mid = 1, and calls itself twice, each with a sublist size of 1, in which case it just returns on both calls. No merging takes place (sort isn't called) until some instance of split(mid, high) returns, which doesn't happen until sublist size is <= 1. It will then start merging larger sublists. The order of merge operations will be depth first / left first on recursively split sublists.

Comment: With bottom up merge sort, there's no recursion, just iteration via two nested loops to merge pairs of sublists (runs), with sublist size starting at 1 and doubling with each pass (outer loop) until sublist size >= array size. Indices or pointers can be used to advance across arrays during the merge process.